# Azure Data Factory. Integration Runtime Self Hosted for data flow debug

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, cloud, azure-data-factory

I am starting with Azure and Azure data factory. I have read some posts were it wasn't recommended to use the AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime for data connections of private data. I have created in a virtual machine a Self hosted integration runtime. Testig this connection in the the dataset it appears to be well created and with successful connection.

I have been able to connect the data through this IR but when I want to activate the option "Data flow debug" in the "Data flow" space the only available option is the AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime. Is this normal? Why does this Self hosted integration runtime not appear?

Thx!

I want to know why in this option my Self hosted IR does not appear.

Comment: As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1342869/linked-service-with-self-hosted-integration-runtim) Self Hosted IR are not supported in dataflows as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Data flows do not execute on self-hosted IR. However, you can use the managed VNET option in the Azure IR in order to open up data flows to data stores inside VNETs or on prem.

Kindly check the below documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-data-flow-private